# How to rename generated multiple report file names for extentreport version 4.0.3?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Using extent report version 4.0.3, multiple reports files are generates (dashboard.html, index.html etc). We need to append date and time stamp to each report file.

Using version 3.1.3, i am able to append date and time stamp to file name as there is single file generated.

```
var htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(dir + "\\Test_Execution_Reports" + "\\Automation_Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".html");
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is no way to rename this file directly from Extent library, I renamed index.html using this simple piece of code:

System.IO.File.Move(oldNameFullPath, newNameFullPath);

This solved my purpose. Hope this helps.